# IP с сервера и с клиента разные

Tags: dns

пингую на сервере Ubuntu имя хоста выдает один айпишник, а на клиенте выдает другой айпишник (клиент ходит через сервер Ubuntu). на клиенте ipconfig /flushdns уже делалКак такое может быть и как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У них разные DNS-сервера?

Они в разных сетях? (в смысле один в "белой", другой в "серой" или оба в разных "серых")Если приведёте все адреса - всё будет яснее.

Comment: были обновлены нс сервера у провайдера, на сервере обновился показывает нужный, а на клиентах которые ходят через этот сервер показывает старый айпи

Comment: ТАки помог утренний рестарт, сервера и клиента

Comment: Наверное достаточно было только клиента (это ж была винда?), но рад был помочь )))